# Noise on my oscilloscope when probing a wire

Tags: noise, oscilloscope, grounding

I am prototyping a NTC voltage divider circuit and I am having trouble with noise on my probe. It seems like I am constantly getting a large amount of noise (200-300mv) on my oscilloscope waveform even when all I am doing is probing a small wire. 200-300 mV is a lot isn't it? I feel like I can't really gauge the actually noisiness of an analog signal if my oscilloscope always has this minimum 200mV p2p noise on it.

[image]

[image]

Where is this noise coming from, and what can I do to remove it?

EDIT: Here are some more picture of the calibrating probe:
[image]
Zoomed in:
[image]

There seems to be a constant 50mV p2p noise signal when calibrating...

Comment: When was the last time you calibrated your oscope?

Comment: That's a nice antenna you've built in your second picture ;)

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've calibrated my oscilloscope. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @marcelm The noise happens even if I probe a line on my breadboard. It's like it doesn't even matter what I am probing.

Comment: @AlexC It's possible. We typically have our oscopes calibrated once a year at my company. (Also, breadboards typically have noise in them due to some stray capacitance.)

Comment: Can you short out the probe tip with the metal shell part of the probe? I mean the two metal parts (pin and shell) that are just a few millimiters apart. If you have those spring probe thingies that clamp on the shell part, you can use those. What does the noise look like if you do that?

Comment: You've made a loop antenna out of your probe in the picture, as @marcelm points out. You're picking up ambient radio noise.

Comment: What should I be probing to limit the radio noise?

Comment: Remove the grounding wires so that there is no loop. Then try to make an electrical connection that is **as short as possible** between the probe tip and the metal ring near the tip of the probe. Some useful accessories to help with that might have been included with the probe. In a pinch, as a test, just use some aluminium or copper foil to make the connection. Then the noise should be gone! If it is not, your probe and/or scope might have an issue. Also see: http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20140929_oscilloscope_probe_tips/index.shtml

Comment: If you look at the lower right side of your 'scope face you'll see a ground terminal and a calibration terminal. Connect the probe ground to the ground terminal and the probe signal clip to the calibration terminal. See if you see any noise. If so, then try the other inputs- might be a bad channel. If not, then the wire probably has an open somewhere. You can also connect the probe signal clip to the ground terminal. skipping the wire entirely. This should give you enough information to figure out the problem...

Comment: Alex, radio noise? possibly: your little loop antenna probe (2nd image) can be oriented to change noise level? Try to measure its frequency. Scan through all the horizontal scales while auto-triggered. Look for a repeating waveform. If you can see a repeating waveform, we might suggest a possible source.

Answer (score 2):

200mV is rather large. It is possible that it is just being picked-up by the antenna formed by your probe connection, but unless you are in a very noisy environment that might be unlikely. It could be that your oscilloscope is defective.

1. Use a BNC termination block directly at the oscilloscope input, is the noise still there? (If you don't have one you can build one by soldering a 50Ω resistor directly inside a BNC connector, alternatively you can just insert a very short piece of wire (e.g., a piece of a paperclip) to short the connector.
2. If your oscilloscope can change the bandwidth (e.g., from 100MHz down to 20MHz) is the magnitude of the noise the same? Is the noise reduced by more than \$\sqrt{5}\$?
3. Is the noise the same for both channels?

Those would all be indications of a noisy input stage or sampling stage to the oscilloscope channels.

If shorting the input directly at the connector removes the noise, then environmental noise is your problem. You would probably have to look into how circuits are grounded and what antenna loops are present in your measurement setup.